# Trying to input date in a better looking manner

Tags: shell, date, input

I'm new to shell script, and I've for a way to input date without
asking the user to put day, month and year one at a time, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ read -p "Enter date: " d
Enter date: 2015-11-30
$ date -d $d
Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 EST 2015
```

you can similarly set the date with `-s` option.